# Adding css border style

Tags: css

Can someone help me, please?. I want to add a border style in the link:hover, to a component of primefaces.
I add like this:

```
.ui-contextmenu .ui-menuitem-link:hover{
  font-weight: bold;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
}
```

In a file calling **pfcrud.css.**
The problem is that, the border style is not working/showing.
Thanks!.

Comment: Welcome to SO, @Jaz. Please update your question to include a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And to improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Does it show up when you hover over it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the shorthand method: `border: thin solid black;`

**CSS**

```
.ui-contextmenu .ui-menuitem-link:hover{
  font-weight: bold;
  border: thin solid black;
}
```

Note that this will change the box-model of the element in question, so when you hover over it this border will effectively increase the element size. You may need to consider accommodating for that change by declaring a rule for the element's natural/default state as well, usually a border with the same width, but `transparent` works in most cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot UncaughtTypeError. It really works!. Regards from Paraguay.

Answer (score 2):

May be this you want to try :

```
.ui-contextmenu .ui-menuitem-link:hover{
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #a32ddf
}
```

Updated fiddle of bucurvad:  https://jsfiddle.net/upq3045g/3/

More info about border at : http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp

Comment: Thanks a lot Priyesh Kumar. It works!. Regards from Paraguay.

Comment: Glad it helped and please accept it as answer it it worked for you.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using

```
.ui-contextmenu .ui-menuitem-link:hover {
border-style: solid black 2px;
}
```

Is this example ok?
https://jsfiddle.net/upq3045g/2/

Comment: @bucurvad You're declaring values for an individual border rule intended for the short hand rule, e.g: `border: 2px solid black`

Comment: 1. Your example is exact the same code from OP ... 2, In your code those values are invalid for border-style , must be just border

Comment: Perhaps, I haven't understood the question correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot bucurvlad. It really works!. Regards from Paraguay